# JSON Object for jqGrid subgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, jqgrid

This is my 3rd question about JSON data for jqGrid's subgrid, till now I did not get a single comment. Please somebody help.

my [1st question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647302/subgrid-in-jqgrid)
and the 
[2nd one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647850/json-string-for-my-jqgrid-subgrid)

I am having trouble getting to know the json format to be used by a subgrid in jqGrid. In my 2nd question i asked about the format that I should be using for a particular scenario

for the given image
[image]

Is this the proper JSON String?

```
var myJSONObject = {
"list": [
    {
        "elementName": "TERM",
        "attribute": [
            {
                "name": "information",
                "firstValue": "Required fixes for AIX",
                "secondValue": "Required fixes for AIX"
            },
            {
                "name": "name",
                "firstValue": "PHCO_34",
                "secondValue": "PHCO_34"
            },
            {
                "name": "version",
                "firstValue": "1.0",
                "secondValue": "2.0"
            }
        ],
        "isEqual": false,
        "isPrasentinXml1": true,
        "isPrasentinXml2": false
    },
    {
        "elementName": "Asian-Core.ASX-JPN-MAN",
        "attribute": [
            {
                "name": "information",
                "firstValue": "Man",
                "secondValue": "Man"
            },
            {
                "name": "name",
                "firstValue": "Asian-Core.ASX-JPN-MAN",
                "secondValue": "Asian-Core.ASX-JPN-MAN"
            },
            {
                "name": "version",
                "firstValue": "B.11.23",
                "secondValue": "B.11.23"
            }
        ],
        "isEqual": false,
        "isPrasentinXml1": true,
        "isPrasentinXml2": true
    }
]
};
```

If yes, my **1st question** this is where i reached so far

```
$('#compareContent').empty();
    $('<div id="compareParentDiv" width="100%">')
    .html('<table id="list2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table>'+
            '<div id="gridpager2"></div></div>')
    .appendTo('#compareContent');

    var grid = jQuery("#list2");

    grid.jqGrid({
        datastr : myJSONObject,
        datatype: 'jsonstring',

        colNames:['Name','Result1', 'Result2'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'elementName',index:'elementName', width:90},
            {name:'isPrasentinXml1',index:'isPrasentinXml1', width:100},
            {name:'isPrasentinXml2',index:'isPrasentinXml2', width:100},
        ],
        pager : '#gridpager2',
        rowNum:10,
        scrollOffset:0,
        height: 'auto',

        autowidth:true,
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        jsonReader: { repeatitems : false, root:"list" },
        subGrid: true,

        /*subGridModel: [{
            //subgrid columns names
            name: ['Name', 'Version', 'Information'],
            //subgrid columns widths
            width: [200, 100, 100],
            //subrig columns aligns
            align: ['left', 'left', 'left']

          }]*/

        // define the icons in subgrid
        subGridOptions: {
            "plusicon"  : "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
            "minusicon" : "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
            "openicon"  : "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e",
            //expand all rows on load
            "expandOnLoad" : true
        },
        subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
            var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
            subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
            pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;
            $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>");
            jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                datastr : myJSONObject,
                datatype: 'jsonstring',
                colNames: ['Name','Value1','Value2'],
                colModel: [
                    {name:"name",index:"name",width:90},
                    {name:"firstValue",index:"firstValue",width:100},
                    {name:"secondValue",index:"secondValue",width:100},
                ],
                rowNum:20,
                pager: pager_id,
                sortname: 'name',
                sortorder: "asc",
                height: 'auto',
                autowidth:true,
                jsonReader: { repeatitems : false, root:"attribute" }
            });
            jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager_id,{edit:false,add:false,del:false})
        }
    });
    grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager2',{add:false,edit:false,del:false});
```

Any type of suggestions/comments/solutions are welcome. Thanks

My output

[image]

Comment: you can verify json at jsonlint.com

Comment: @3nigma: Good resource, Also I needed to know for this particular subgrid is my json string good enought, because the subgrid does not get populated

Comment: @Oleg: Please take a look at my questions :)

Comment: can you post a link  to documentation i think the datatype should be `json` instead of `jsonstring`

Comment: @3nigma: Here is the doc.. http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data

Comment: @Abhishek Simon: To send a message to me you should write a comment to a question/answer **where I wrote something**. If you just write "@Oleg" text in the comment to your new question I receive no notification about this. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) for details.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks i'll do that next time :)

Comment: @Oleg: Please can you take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662475/treegrid-in-jqgrid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code has small errors in the declaration of the `myJSONObject` variable and the code which create the contain of the `div#compareContent` should be fixed to

```
$('#compareContent').empty();
$('<div id="compareParentDiv" width="100%">'+
  '<table id="list2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table>'+
        '<div id="gridpager2"></div></div>')
.appendTo('#compareContent');
```

Small other syntax errors are the trailing commas in the `colModel`: the comma before ']' should be removed.

Now to your main problem. You should change `datastr : myJSONObject` in the subgrid to something like

```
datastr : myJSONObject.list[0]
```

then the modified demo will show the data: see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/abhisheksimon.htm).

One more problem which you has is the absent of ids in your data. You should modify the structure of the data to define the unique ids for very grid row and every subgrid row. You should take in the considerations that ids from the data will be used as id of `<tr>` elements and HTML don't permit to have id duplicates on one HTML page.

**UPDATED**: See [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/abhisheksimon1.htm) an example of modification of your JSON input and the jqGrid so that ids will be used.

Comment: Thanks for replying, your answer made me leap 90%, there is still 1 problem, When I have multiple rows, I just get the 1st rows subdata, Please check my updated question for screenshot and json string for more than 1 row.

Comment: @Oleg: +1 for jqgrid subgrid problem

Comment: @Abhishek Simon: I modified [the second demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/abhisheksimon1.htm) where 1) I included ids for your data 2) included `page: function() { return 1; }` in the `jsonReader` 3) set `expandOnLoad : false` which are the main problem. In my opinion the new setting is very buggy (see my [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459900/jqgrid-subgrid-doesnt-populate-with-data/6467539#6467539)) and I don't recommend you to use it.

Comment: @Abhishek Simon: You are welcome! One more small remark. If you want use data paging, you should include in the data the number of current page and other paging information. If you will not use paging you should replace `rowNum:10` and `rowNum:20` in the subgrid with and large value like `rowNum:10000`. Currently if you would has more as 10 or 20 items of data only the first 10 or 20 will be shown and you will see no error or warning.

Comment: @Oleg: I won't be using paging in my subgrid, but i require paging in the parent grid. Do I still need data in the number of current page and other paging information?

Comment: @Abhishek Simon: You can see on the demo that the paging buttons are disable, so the user are not able to go to the next page. To have there enabled you should has the total number of pages grater as the current page number. So it you want to use the **server side** data paging you need include `page` and `total` inside of you JSON data. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data).

Comment: @Oleg: I'll take that into consideration. Thanks again for your support. :)

Comment: @Oleg: Is there any other way I can have pagination apart from getting it from the JSON, may be i'll override some method or assign it later?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your last question. What do you mean under "to have pagination apart from getting it from the JSON"? Which scenario of the pagination you plan?

Comment: @Oleg: I need to have pagination but since you said i need to get pagination information from the server, is there any other way, like assigning pagination at the client side?

Comment: @Oleg let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1343/discussion-between-abhishek-simon-and-oleg)

Answer (score 1):

a couple of suggestion that may/maynot workout

when using subgrid select the grid as

```
var mygrid = jQuery("#mygrid")[0];
```

replace

```
var grid = jQuery("#list2");
```

with

```
var grid = jQuery("#list2")[0];
```

Ref: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/2-questions-about-jqgrid-subgrid-and-jsonstring

also change your json to a `valid` json

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "elementName": "TERM",
            "attribute": [
                {
                    "name": "information",
                    "firstValue": "RequiredfixesforAIX",
                    "secondValue": "RequiredfixesforAIX"
                },
                {
                    "name": "name",
                    "firstValue": "PHCO_34",
                    "secondValue": "PHCO_34"
                },
                {
                    "name": "version",
                    "firstValue": "1.0",
                    "secondValue": "2.0"
                }
            ],
            "isEqual": false,
            "isPrasentinXml1": true,
            "isPrasentinXml2": false
        }
    ]
}
```

verfified by www.jsonlint.com

you may find the following link useful

[jqGrid with JSON data renders table as empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259435/jqgrid-with-json-data-renders-table-as-empty)

Comment: Thanks for replying +1. I checked my JSON string in your link, it's correct. Also `var mygrid = jQuery("#mygrid")[0];` what should i replace it with?

Comment: `var grid = jQuery("#list2");` is for the parent grid. if I replace this with `var grid = jQuery("#list2")[0];` the table will not be displayed.