# filter and apply background color to tr in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I have this code which gives me the below output in firebug, so according to this output I can filter the `td` and assign a different background color, Right?

[image: screenshot]

My code

```
loadComplete: function() {
            var i, names=this.p.groupingView.sortnames[0], l = names.length;
            for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
                if (names[i]==='envVariable') {
                    $(this).jqGrid('groupingToggle',this.id+"ghead_"+i);
                } else {
                    // hide the grouping row
                    $('#'+this.id+"ghead_"+i).hide();
                }
            }
            var getColumnIndexByName = function(grid, columnName) {
                var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel'),i=0,l=cm.length;
                for (; i<l; i++) {
                    if (cm[i].name===columnName) {
                        return i; // return the index
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            };

            var iCol = getColumnIndexByName($(this),'isEqual'),
            cRows = this.rows.length, iRow, row, className;
            for (iRow=0; iRow<cRows; iRow++) {
                row = this.rows[iRow];
                className = row.className;
                if ($.inArray('jqgrow', className.split(' ')) > 0) { // $(row).hasClass('jqgrow')

//this prints into console
                    console.info(row.cells[iCol]);

//here i am trying to apply filter                      
$(row.cells[iCol])
                    .filter("false")
                    .css("background", "#c8ebcc",
                            "background-color", "#DCFFFF",
                            "background-image", "none");

                }
            }

        }
```

## **Updated**

@Oleg: I need to hide all the rows that has **isEqual** as **true** and show only rows having **isEqual** as **false** with all changed background color. So i modified your code something like below, but it does not hide the rows, it just displays the whole thing, without any change, where am i going wrong?

```
var i, l, data = this.p.data, rows = this.rows, item;

            l = data.length;
            for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
                item = data[i];
                if (!item.isEqual) {

                    $(rows.namedItem(item._id_))
                    .css({
                        "background-color": "#DCFFFF",
                        "background-image": "none"
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    $(rows.namedItem(item._id_)).hide();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question because it's unclear, right? :)

Comment: @aliecas: :) I read in jquery [doc](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) that i can apply filter to any element and apply css to it, So in my code i have used [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start) plugin to create a grid, I want to have background color of `tr` to be changed from usual, when it acquires a `false` value from json string, at the bottom of my code i have identified when i get a `false` value for `isEqual` (from json string) and I just need to change the corresponding `tr`'s bkg color, in this case `td`'s bkg color

Comment: you want all td with title false to get the same background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, that your current question continues [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662475/something-similar-to-treegrid-in-jqgrid). In the case you use **local** data and you can very easy get the contain of all grid data. You can first define the additional the hidden grid column:

```
{ name: 'isEqual', index: 'isEqual', width: 100, hidden:true }
```

and then append `loadComplete` with the following code:

```
var i, l, data = this.p.data, rows = this.rows, item;

l = data.length;
for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
    item = data[i];
    if (!item.isEqual) {
        $(rows.namedItem(item._id_))
            .css({
                "background-color": "#DCFFFF",
                "background-image": "none"
            });
    }
}
```

The results will be

[image]

See the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AbhishekSimon3.htm).

Comment: I also need one more thing, I need to hide all the rows that has `isEqual` as true and show only rows having `isEqual` as false with all changed background color, Please see my updated question i made modifications in the code.

Comment: @Abhishek Simon: Look at [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AbhishekSimon4.htm) for example.

Comment: Thats great, you can solve anything :) but where was i going wrong? I also wrote `$(rows.namedItem(item._id_)).hide();`

Comment: Also where does `p` come from  `data = this.p.data, rows = this.rows, item;`

Comment: @Abhishek Simon: Look at the part with `$(rows.namedItem(this.id+"ghead_"+ i)).find("span.ui-icon").click`. Inside of the most jqGrid event handler `this` is DOM of the `<table>` element which has `rows` property independent on jqGrid. `this.p` is jqGrid extension. It hold all [jqGrid options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options). You can use `$('#list').jQuery('getGridParam','data')` to get `$('#list')[0].p` or `this.p.data`.

Comment: Thanks, after this is over I am going to sit over jqgrid and try as much feature as possible :)

Comment: @Abhishek Simon: First of all you should examine [the official jqGrid demo page](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) to know all the main possibilities.

Comment: Please take a look at [this continuing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692086/why-does-my-grouping-in-jqgrid-behave-differently) I am getting some weird behavior when having pagination

Comment: Please look at [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939096/hide-grouping-heading-in-jqgrid-if-every-row-inside-it-is-hidden)