# Weird behavior of jqgrid Grouping

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Continuing from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692086/why-does-my-grouping-in-jqgrid-behave-differently/6694100#6694100) which was solved by @Oleg.

The solution seems to work when the data is less, but when the increased, it is behaving somewhat same as my previous problem.

Initially the grid displays only **two groupings** (actually 3), when I go to next page (**2 pages** in total, each page contains **14 rows**) it shows 1 grouping, but when I come back to my initial page, (after hitting the pagination) now it displays all the **3 groupings**. Please help fixing this problem.

Below are the 3 screen shots (1st before pagination, 2nd after pagination hit, 3rd.. comeback to 1st page).

**Update** 
Indifferent behavior when data is large. Now it has 4 groups but one of them is shown in next page.

My **jqgrid code** `var grouping=new Array("Environment", "system", "IIRServers","product");`

```
$('#compareContent').empty();
        $('<div id="compareParentDiv">'+
          '<table id="list2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table>'+
                '<div id="gridpager3"></div></div>')
        .appendTo('#compareContent');

        $("#compareParentDiv").hide();

        var gridDiff = $("#list2");
        gridDiff.jqGrid({
            datastr: compareData,
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            colNames: ['KeyName', 'SubCategory', starheader, header1,'isEqual'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'elementName', index: 'elementName', width: 150 },
                { name: 'subCategory', index: 'subCategory', width: 1 },
                { name: 'firstValue', index: 'firstValue', width: 300, jsonmap:'attribute.0.firstValue' },
                { name: 'secondValue', index: 'secondValue', width: 300,jsonmap:'attribute.0.secondValue' },
                { name: 'isEqual', index: 'isEqual', width: 1,hidden:true}
            ],

            pager: '#gridpager3',
            //rowNum: 14,
            scrollOffset:1,
            viewrecords: true,

            //rownumbers: true,
            height: 'auto',
            autowidth:true,
            grouping: true,
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                page: function(){return 1;},
                root: "response"
            },

            groupingView: {
                groupField: ['subCategory'],
                groupOrder: ['desc'],
                //groupDataSorted : true,
                groupColumnShow: [false],
                //groupCollapse: true,
                groupText: ['<b>{0} - {1} Item(s)</b>']
            },

            loadComplete: function() {
                if (this.p.datatype !== 'local') {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                       gridDiff.trigger('reloadGrid');
                   }, 0);
                } else {
                    $("#compareParentDiv").show();
                }

                var i, names=this.p.groupingView.sortnames[0], l = names.length;
                for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
                    if ($.inArray(names[i],grouping) >= 0) {
                        $(this).jqGrid('groupingToggle',this.id+"ghead_"+i);
                    } else {
                        // hide the grouping row
                        $('#'+this.id+"ghead_"+i).hide();
                    }
                }
                var i, l, data = this.p.data, rows = this.rows, item;
                l = data.length;
                for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
                    item = data[i];
                    if (!item.isEqual) {
                        $(rows.namedItem(item._id_))
                            .css({
                                "background-color": "#FFE3EA",
                                "background-image": "none"
                            });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        gridDiff.jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridpager3', { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true });
```

my **JSON**

```
    {
"response": [
{
  "id": "1",
  "elementName": "rulebaseserver",
  "category": "product",
  "subCategory": "IIRServers",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "rulebaseserver",
      "firstValue": "ssasvck> Server 'benz:7668' is up\u000a",
      "secondValue": "ssasvck> Attempt 1 at server 'estilo:45687'\u000assasvck> Server 'estilo:45687' is down\u000a"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "elementName": "xmlsyncserver",
  "category": "product",
  "subCategory": "IIRServers",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "xmlsyncserver",
      "firstValue": "ssasvck> Attempt 1 at server 'localhost:-1'\u000assasvck> Server 'localhost:-1' is down\u000a",
      "secondValue": "ssasvck> Attempt 1 at server 'estilo:45689'\u000assasvck> Server 'estilo:45689' is down\u000a"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "elementName": "SSANUL",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": true,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/dev/null",
      "secondValue": "/dev/null"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "4",
  "elementName": "SSA_LIHOST",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "benz:7660",
      "secondValue": "estilo:45682"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "5",
  "elementName": "SSH_CLIENT",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "10.65.6.131 1402 22",
      "secondValue": "10.65.6.131 2138 22"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "6",
  "elementName": "HOSTTYPE",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "secondValue": "x86_64-linux"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "7",
  "elementName": "DB2DIR",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/databases/db2v8_32bit"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "8",
  "elementName": "PWD",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/home/srkalya1/csm",
      "secondValue": "/home/hqusers1/csm"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "9",
  "elementName": "JAVA_LIB",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/home/srkalya1/csm/lib",
      "secondValue": "/home/hqusers1/csm/lib"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "10",
  "elementName": "MACHTYPE",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "secondValue": "x86_64"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "11",
  "elementName": "NLSPATH",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": true,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat",
      "secondValue": "/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "12",
  "elementName": "SSA_PRODUCT",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "iss",
      "secondValue": "iir"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "13",
  "elementName": "xmlconsoleserver",
  "category": "product",
  "subCategory": "IIRServers",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "xmlconsoleserver",
      "firstValue": "ssasvck> Attempt 1 at server 'localhost:-1'\u000assasvck> Server 'localhost:-1' is down\u000a",
      "secondValue": "ssasvck> Attempt 1 at server 'estilo:45691'\u000assasvck> Server 'estilo:45691' is down\u000a"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "14",
  "elementName": "SHLIB_PATH",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/data/ODBC5.1_32/lib:.:/usr/lib:/lib:/databases/sybase12.5.2_64BIT/OCS-12_5/lib:/databases/oracle9.2.0.6/lib32:/databases/db2v8_32bit/lib:/databases/sybase12.5.2_64BIT/OCS-12_5/lib:/home/srkalya1/IIR_901_HPUX/bin"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "15",
  "elementName": "numberofcpu",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "system",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "numberofcpu",
      "firstValue": "2\u000a",
      "secondValue": "4\u000a"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "16",
  "elementName": "PATH",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/home/srkalya1/IIR_901_HPUX/bin:/home/srkalya1/IDQ_PC_860_Integration/bin:/bin:.:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/local/bin:/opt/aCC/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/local/etc:/etc:/usr/etc:.:/databases/oracle9.2.0.6/bin:/databases/sybase12.5.2_64BIT/OCS-12_5/bin:/databases/db2v8_32bit/bin:/data/ODBC5.1_32/bin",
      "secondValue": "/home/hqusers1/IIR_1152825121_estilo_9.0.1SP2_32/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "17",
  "elementName": "avail",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "14635072"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "18",
  "elementName": "SSATEMP",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/home/srkalya1/tmp",
      "secondValue": "/home/hqusers1/tmp"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "19",
  "elementName": "SSAOPTS",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": true,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "+L",
      "secondValue": "+L"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "20",
  "elementName": "SSA_XMPORT",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "7670",
      "secondValue": "45688"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "21",
  "elementName": "SSA_RBPORT",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "7668",
      "secondValue": "45687"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "22",
  "elementName": "SSA_SEHOST",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "benz:7666",
      "secondValue": "estilo:45684"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "23",
  "elementName": "SSA_SEPORT",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "7666",
      "secondValue": "45684"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "24",
  "elementName": "SSAWORKDIR",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/home/srkalya1/IIR_901_HPUX/ids",
      "secondValue": "/home/hqusers1/IIR_1152825121_estilo_9.0.1SP2_32/ids"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "25",
  "elementName": "NLS_LANG",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "American_America.AL32UTF8"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "26",
  "elementName": "TZ",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "IST-5:30"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "27",
  "elementName": "SSAGREP",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": true,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/bin/grep",
      "secondValue": "/bin/grep"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "28",
  "elementName": "ORACLE_HOME",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/databases/oracle9.2.0.6"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "29",
  "elementName": "A",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "26214400"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "30",
  "elementName": "SSABIN",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/home/srkalya1/IIR_901_HPUX/bin",
      "secondValue": "/home/hqusers1/IIR_1152825121_estilo_9.0.1SP2_32/bin"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "31",
  "elementName": "MANPATH",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/usr/share/man/%L:/usr/share/man:/usr/contrib/man/%L:/usr/contrib/man:/usr/local/man/%L:/usr/local/man:/opt/mx/share/man:/opt/sec_mgmt/share/man:/usr/dt/share/man:/opt/samba/man:/opt/resmon/share/man:/opt/gnome/man:/opt/perf/man/%L:/opt/perf/man:/opt/ignite/share/man/%L:/opt/ignite/share/man:/opt/wbem/share/man:/opt/prm/man/%L:/opt/prm/man:/opt/sec_mgmt/share/man/%L:/opt/ssh/share/man:/opt/graphics/common/man:/opt/mqm/man:/opt/sentinel/man/%L:/opt/sentinel/man:/opt/langtools/share/man/%L:/opt/langtools/share/man"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "32",
  "elementName": "SSA_CSPORT",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "7669",
      "secondValue": "1669"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "33",
  "elementName": "version",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "system",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "version",
      "firstValue": "U\u000a",
      "secondValue": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga)\u000a"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "34",
  "elementName": "U",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "11579328"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "35",
  "elementName": "SSAAWK",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": true,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/bin/awk",
      "secondValue": "/bin/awk"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "36",
  "elementName": "OCLIB",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/databases/sybase12.5.2_64BIT/OCS-12_5/lib"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "37",
  "elementName": "TNS_ADMIN",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/home/srkalya1"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "38",
  "elementName": "LOGNAME",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "srkalya1",
      "secondValue": "hqusers1"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "39",
  "elementName": "SSA_RBHOST",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "benz:7668",
      "secondValue": "estilo:45687"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "40",
  "elementName": "__ARIES_PA_AOUT_MAXSSIZ",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "8388608"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "41",
  "elementName": "_",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": true,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/bin/env",
      "secondValue": "/bin/env"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "42",
  "elementName": "xmlsearchserver",
  "category": "product",
  "subCategory": "IIRServers",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "xmlsearchserver",
      "firstValue": "ssasvck> Server 'benz:7670' is up\u000a",
      "secondValue": "ssasvck> Attempt 1 at server 'estilo:45688'\u000assasvck> Server 'estilo:45688' is down\u000a"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "43",
  "elementName": "SSABASEDIR",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/home/srkalya1/IIR_901_HPUX/ids",
      "secondValue": "/home/hqusers1/IIR_1152825121_estilo_9.0.1SP2_32/ids"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "44",
  "elementName": "maxthreadsperproc",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "system",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "maxthreadsperproc",
      "firstValue": "                    256  \u000a",
      "secondValue": "2000000\u000a"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "45",
  "elementName": "cpuspeed",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "system",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "cpuspeed",
      "firstValue": "1400\u000a",
      "secondValue": " 1862.054\u000a"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "46",
  "elementName": "mempagesize",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "system",
  "isEqual": true,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "mempagesize",
      "firstValue": "4096\u000a",
      "secondValue": "4096\u000a"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "47",
  "elementName": "GROUP",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "secondValue": "support"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "48",
  "elementName": "connectionserver",
  "category": "product",
  "subCategory": "IIRServers",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "connectionserver",
      "firstValue": "ssasvck> Server 'benz:7667' is up\u000a",
      "secondValue": "ssasvck> Attempt 1 at server 'estilo:45685'\u000assasvck> Server 'estilo:45685' is down\u000a"
    }
  ]
},

{
  "id": "67",
  "elementName": "ssaname3server",
  "category": "product",
  "subCategory": "IIRServers",
  "isEqual": true,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "ssaname3server",
      "firstValue": "ssasvck> Attempt 1 at server 'null:-1'\u000assasvck> Server 'null:-1' is down\u000a",
      "secondValue": "ssasvck> Attempt 1 at server 'null:-1'\u000assasvck> Server 'null:-1' is down\u000a"
    }
  ]
},

{
  "id": "70",
  "elementName": "osname",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "system",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "osname",
      "firstValue": "HP-UX\u000a",
      "secondValue": "Linux\u000a"
    }
  ]
},

{
  "id": "73",
  "elementName": "bitmode",
  "category": "product",
  "subCategory": "product",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "bitmode",
      "firstValue": "/home/srkalya1/IIR_901_HPUX/bin/libssaiok.so:\u0009ELF-64 shared object file - IA64\u000a",
      "secondValue": "/home/hqusers1/IIR_1152825121_estilo_9.0.1SP2_32/bin/libssaiok.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped\u000a"
    }
  ]
},

{
  "id": "76",
  "elementName": "hostname",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "system",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "hostname",
      "firstValue": "benz\u000a",
      "secondValue": "estilo\u000a"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "77",
  "elementName": "machine",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "system",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "machine",
      "firstValue": "ia64 hp server rx2600\u000a",
      "secondValue": "x86_64\u000a"
    }
  ]
},

{
  "id": "82",
  "elementName": "release",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "system",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "release",
      "firstValue": "B.11.23\u000a",
      "secondValue": "2.6.18-128.el5\u000a"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "83",
  "elementName": "SSA_ARCH",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "IA64",
      "secondValue": "X86"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "84",
  "elementName": "ssaname3webserviceserver",
  "category": "product",
  "subCategory": "IIRServers",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "ssaname3webserviceserver",
      "firstValue": "ssasvck> Attempt 1 at server 'null:-1'\u000assasvck> Server 'null:-1' is down\u000a",
      "secondValue": "ssasvck> Attempt 1 at server 'null:-1'\u000assasvck> Server 'null:-1' is down\u000a"
    }
  ]
},

{
  "id": "91",
  "elementName": "__ARIES_PA_STACK_SIZE_cur",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "8388608"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "92",
  "elementName": "consoleserver",
  "category": "product",
  "subCategory": "IIRServers",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "consoleserver",
      "firstValue": "ssasvck> Server 'benz:7669' is up\u000a",
      "secondValue": "ssasvck> Attempt 1 at server 'localhost:1669'\u000assasvck> Server 'localhost:1669' is down\u000a"
    }
  ]
},

{
  "id": "98",
  "elementName": "maxfilesperproc",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "system",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "maxfilesperproc",
      "firstValue": " 4096\u000a",
      "secondValue": "32\u000a"
    }
  ]
},

{
  "id": "100",
  "elementName": "licenseserver",
  "category": "product",
  "subCategory": "IIRServers",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "licenseserver",
      "firstValue": "ssasvck> Server 'benz:7660' is up\u000a",
      "secondValue": "ssasvck> Attempt 1 at server 'estilo:45682'\u000assasvck> Server 'estilo:45682' is down\u000a"
    }
  ]
},

{
  "id": "103",
  "elementName": "SSA_CXPORT",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "",
      "secondValue": "45691"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "104",
  "elementName": "httpsearchserver",
  "category": "product",
  "subCategory": "IIRServers",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "httpsearchserver",
      "firstValue": "ssasvck> Attempt 1 at server 'localhost:-1'\u000assasvck> Server 'localhost:-1' is down\u000a",
      "secondValue": "ssasvck> Attempt 1 at server 'estilo:45690'\u000assasvck> Server 'estilo:45690' is down\u000a"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "105",
  "elementName": "SSA_COPORT",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "7667",
      "secondValue": "45685"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "106",
  "elementName": "HOME",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/home/srkalya1",
      "secondValue": "/home/hqusers1"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "107",
  "elementName": "ATHANOR_HOME",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "/home/srkalya1/IDQ_PC_860_Integration"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "108",
  "elementName": "SSA_XMHOST",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "benz:7670",
      "secondValue": "estilo:45688"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "109",
  "elementName": "BITMODE",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "32"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "110",
  "elementName": "DB2INSTANCE",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "db8inst1"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "111",
  "elementName": "SSA_HTHOST",
  "category": "system",
  "subCategory": "Environment",
  "isEqual": false,



  "attribute": [
    {
      "firstValue": "",
      "secondValue": "estilo:45690"
    }
  ]
}
],
 "xls_path": "\\csm\\files\\comparefiles\\compare_output.xls"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug in jqGrid. The problem exist because you use `datatype: "jsonstring"` with **unsorted** data (the data are not sorted by 'subCategory'). At the beginning the data will be displayed like it was filled. After you goes back to the first page the data will be already sorted locally by jqGrid. After that you can goes many time on the next page and back to the first page and have the same results.

You can solve the problem in another way. The best will be to fill the items of the `myJson` sorted by `subCategory`. If you can't do this you can do the following. Just include in the `loadComplete` the following lines

```
if (this.p.datatype !== 'local') {
    setTimeout(function () {
        gridDiff.trigger('reloadGrid');
    }, 0);
}
```

It will reload the grid immediately after the first filling. At the end of loading the `datatype` will be changed to `datatype = 'local'`, so no reloading of the grid will be not done any time later. The only disadvantage will be small flicker at the loading of the grid. If needed you can place the grid inside of hidden div at the beginning and make the div visible after the second loading of the grid:

```
$("#compareParentDiv").hide();
...
gridDiff.jqGrid({
    loadComplete: function () {
        if (this.p.datatype !== 'local') {
            ... // see before
        } else {
            $("#compareParentDiv").show();
        }
        ....
    }
};
```

One more small remark. The data in the `elementName` column are **not unique** (see elementName='maxfilesperproc' and id=8 and id=98). So you should remove `key:true` from the `elementName` column definition. In the case the `id` will be used as the rowid.

The last remark. You can use [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) if you test existence of `names[i]` in the `grouping` array. The changed code fragment could be

```
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if ($.inArray(names[i], grouping) >= 0) {
        $(this).jqGrid('groupingToggle', this.id + "ghead_" + i);
    } else {
        // hide the grouping row
        $('#' + this.id + "ghead_" + i).hide();
    }
}
```

See the modified demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AbhishekSimon6.htm).

Comment: When the data is very large, like more than 3 groups, it only displays 3 group in one page, the problem is when the user sees the initial page he should be able to see more than that

Comment: @Abhishek: You don't set and `rowNum`. So the default `rowNum:20` will be used. With paging on jqGrid display one the groups from the **current** page. I suppose that you want to have **no data paging** and display all the data on one page in the collapsed form. In the case you should use `rowNum` with any large value like `rowNum:10000`.

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem, now all the groups are getting displayed as expected